# "aware of how..." vs. "aware how..." and "stressful to..." vs. "stressful for..."

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, prepositions, adjectives

Can someone please help me with this sentence:

> It's not like you weren't aware of how stressful this would be to me.

Is it supposed to be *aware* or *aware of*? And is it supposed to be stressful *to* me or *for* me?

Thanks!

Comment: I think both _aware_ and _aware of_ are acceptable and common.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Do you know if it's supposed to be stressful _to_ me or _for_ me?

Comment: _for_ sounds more natural to me, but I think both are probably acceptable. What research have you done?

Comment: Sally--have you looked up these words?  It's expected on ELU that you've done some research on your own.

Comment: Yes, I have looked them up, but unfortunately I didn't find anything that made me wiser.

Answer (score -1):

Aware of must be followed by a noun. Are you aware of the way in which would be acceptable, whereas 'aware of how' is not.

Comment: This isn't correct. If you believe it is, please [edit] your answer to provide authoritative evidence or argument in support of your claim. For further guidance, see [answer], and take the [Tour]. :-)